# Do you have to run WordPress locally to edit HTML in view layer?

Tags: wordpress

I can't find how to edit the HTML. I want to get rid of small tags and change formatting from a template I am using, is that possible? There's HTML to be inserted into a post like a blog post but it only affects the post not the page.

Do I have to run WordPress on my local machine to get access to the code for the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your theme's code trough FTP and you can find it in 'wp-content/themes/yourtheme'. You can alter this code, but the best practice is to use a Child Theme.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

It does involve some programming knowledge to get going, but once set up properly you can safely edit the files without loosing changes after a theme update.